# How does the compiler differentiate typedef struct implementation with the type having the same name as the structure?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, typedef, cs50

I've been studying singly linked lists and crossed with two different `typedef struct` implementations.

1st (at CS50 lecture explanation):

```c
// Represents a node:

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
}
node;
```

2nd (at CS50 short videos explanation):

```c
typedef struct sllist
{
    int number;
    struct sllist *next;
}
sllnode;
```

My question is:
In the former implementation, how is the compiler able to differentiate between `node`, the alias and `node`, the `struct`?
Why is it able to differentiate `struct` from `typedef`, but I cannot use the same variable name for representing `int` and `string`, for example?

Comment: They are put in different 'namespaces' or 'categories'.

Comment: The one is `struct node` and the other is `node` which will be the same thing, but with `*next;` as a self referencing member `node` isn't yet defined, so it has to be `struct node`.

Comment: While for C++ (and thus _not_ plain C and _there are differences_), https://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/2864740 might be a nice read. It also includes links to C resources. I was not able to find a similar C-specific answer on SO quickly, although it should be possible to use such to search out.

Answer (score 2):

> how is the compiler able to differentiate between node, the alias and node, the struct?

Pretty easy: they are two different things. One is preceded by the `struct` keyword, one is not. The `typedef` can be seen as creating an alias. If the compiler sees `node` alone, it looks at the `typedef` to get the real type, while if it sees `struct node` it already knows the type.

> Why is it able to differentiate struct from typedef, but I cannot use the same variable name for representing int and string, for example?

That's a different scenario. You cannot re-define a type name that already exists. You cannot do `typedef something int;` because `int` already exists, the same way as you cannot do:

```
struct s {
    int a;
};

struct s {
    int a;
};
```

This single definition rule also applies to variable names and function names.